# x86 program arguments location

Tags: windows, x86, command-line-arguments, x86-64, assembly

I'm writing a windows app that prints the comman line arguments in assembly. I have all the processing code. What I need to know is where the program arguments are located on the stack

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The command-line arguments are not really passed on the stack. The official way to get a pointer to the command line is to call the KERNEL32 function GetCommandLine.

Comment: @Cole: they aren't passed on the stack by Windows.  You get `argv` in a C program because the C runtime initialization calls `GetCommandLine()` and parses it into the `argv` array before calling `main()`.